# Difference Between Two PostgreSQL Queries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I saw following queries in my code and want to make sure I understand them correctly.

Table Name - TABLENAME
Columns - id (varchar2),  data (bytes)

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET data= data || 'bytes' WHERE id = 'X';
UPDATE TABLENAME SET data = 'bytes' WHERE id = 'X';
```

I think one is appending and other is updating the blob. Can someone please confirm that?

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking a question ever as far as I'm concerned, but did you also try a simple test to come to some kind of conclusion?

Comment: Yes - i did I\but I was not able to see inside the blobs apart from increase in size. So that's why I wanted to confirm with expert people on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is correct, `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL (and Postgres). [Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)